# How to crop images without bloating file size

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, file-size

Creating image comparison graphics for my thesis, I have a few figures with some 50-100 pngs each.

Each of the images has a 1920 by 1080 resolution, but they are clipped to a 300 by 300 window.

The problem is that the output pdf is about 300 MB in size, which makes it a pain to work with.

I have tried various compression programs (Adobe's, PDF24, Ghostscript), but none of them can shrink the file much without compromising quality.

My last idea would be to have imagemagick automatically crop the images before including them, but I ran into errors before when trying to customize `\includegraphics`.

Here's what I have so far for that (not very robust):

```
\newcommand{\croppedimage}[3]{%
    \immediate\write18{magick convert #2 -gravity SouthWest -crop #3 +repage #2.crop-#3.png}%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2.crop-#3.png}%
}
...
%\includegraphics[width=15mm,clip,viewport=550 550 850 850]{some/file.png}
\croppedimage{width=15mm}{300x300+550+550}{some/file.png}
```

But this creates a bunch of extra files alongside the originals. Is there a way to get a temporary directory (preferably with caching)?

`\DeclareGraphicsRule` seems to be close to what I want, but I don't know if there is any way to access any arguments beside the file name?

I have considered doing this manually, but I am a very indecisive person and I will likely change my mind about the exact viewport I want.

Comment: You could use `write18` to manually invoke the `magick` command, but I personally have no idea on implementing caching (and having `magick` rerun every time you're building your document will eventually be at least annoying). Another suggestion would be using a `Makefile` to build your document (but this way detecting if your "viewport" changed won't be easy, but you'll have some sort of caching (only reruns `magick` if the input image changed)).  Maybe someone with more experience will come by and can help you more, this is what I can offer with my knowledge

Comment: There really is no advantage to doing this inside latex, just do it when needed, set up a script or bach file or whatever  so you only have to put the image magic options in one place and can loop through all the images and place them in whatever folder sructure you want.

Comment: I would use a short document in `standalone` class to crop each image individually, and then include the cropped images directly into the larger document.

Comment: I would definitely crop them with imagemagick before trying to insert them into the document. You said you had trouble "customizing" `\includegraphics`, What kind of trouble? Was removing the `crop` and `viewport` options not enough?

Comment: @frabjous before the issue was expanding macros in the viewport parameter. The current code in the question based on the first comment kinda works.
Thank you all for the ideas!